# Duplicate Resource Names

Tags: rest, identifier

I'm designing a Service Catalog of Rest APIs and coming up with best practices so that many developers can contribute.  Here is my question

Say I have a resource called Saturn. (in reality I know this can be an identifier)  In the catalog it could be a resource relating to a planet or a roman god.  So I could have:

```
/gods/saturn  or
/planets/saturn
```

Each Saturn resource returns a different representation.  These are really different resources sharing the same name.  Looking for advice on how to handle in a Pragmatic Rest way to manage resources.

Answer (score 0):

@John Kirby

these:

- /gods/saturn
- /planets/saturn

are two different identifiers. it doesn't actually matter how you store data in backend and which segment of URI you use to identify them, but from REST point of view the URI as a whole(even including query string) is a resource identifier.